# What programming language for a webserver

Tags: java, c++, performance, webserver

What should be the programming language chosen for web server.
The only thing I'm looking for is efficiency, doesn't matter how much time will it take to develop.

I recently saw some benchmarks where results show JAVA faster.
I don't know how much those benchmark programs are relevant to developing a web server.

Well, my practical experience says C++ is faster than JAVA(I'm assuming C is generally faster than C++).

Please advise,
Mayank

Comment: Assembly language still has to be compiled and I bet some assembly compilers under super rare instances produce sub-optimal opcodes. Personally I would break out a hex editor and write the whole thing by hand. Start with the executable header and go from there.

Comment: [Mel](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~elb/folklore/mel.html) would do it by hand in machine code and optimize the byte layout on disk to take into account the drive's spin rate.

Comment: taspeotis, are you crazy? Everyone knows that the fastest webservers are implemented in FPGAs.

Comment: childish question. Before thinking about which language, you should come up with a GREAT architecture, which should let you implement all the stuff required by a modern webserver while using all the concurrent capabilities offered by modern CPUs. And don't even try to talk about "language speed" in general, which is essentially meaningless.

Comment: *I'm assuming C is generally faster than C++* - false

Comment: @Justin ` 
I'm assuming C is **generally** faster than C++ - false`. Why?

Comment: @Mayank it was designed to be as fast as C (and can actually be faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many languages that can be used to write a Web server, and many languages have already been used to write webservers.

Java is used to build Apache Tomcat and the Jetty Web Server.  Resin is another example of a Web server written in Java.

The [Apache Web Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) was written in C.

The POW Webserver was written on Mozilla's Development Platform as an extension to Firefox.

In summary, you can use any language to build a Web server, but the language of choice depends on your goals.  I'm assuming if efficiency is your goal then you need something super fast.  I believe C was used to build Apache for this very reason, and is why Apache serves roughly 60% of the Web sites on the Internet.

Comment: Did you read the whole question?

Comment: The question wasn't very clear.  In fact, it's probably going to be closed as not a real question.

Comment: The question is quite clear. It's just... not that good a question.

Comment: @Ignacio - I added a little more detail to properly address the question.  Thanks.